# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sheet' of null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS, and run in to a problem after changing this function:

```
gList :  function (){
return List
},
```

With this:

```
gList :  function() {
$http({method:'GET',url:'/sessions'}).
    success(function(data){
        return data;
    }).
    error(function(data){
        $log.info(data);
    })},
```

And now I receive this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sheet' of null
(anonymous function)    modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4
y   modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4
s.fontface  modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4
(anonymous function)    modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4
(anonymous function)    modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4
```

The function is called here:

```
$scope.sessions = Sessions.gList();
```

Then

```
ng-repeat="session in sessions"
```

While I don't even use `sheet` in my code. Help?

Comment: well some part of the code (somewhere) obviously need the return value from your old function when it has been called. your new function (may) return some value at a later point in time. until then whatever the old method returned is now null.

Comment: @DatProgram The function is called here: 

$scope.sessions = Sessions.gList();

Wouldn't it try to evaluate the function?

Comment: Have you tried using the javascript debugger to find the place where he hits the "sheet" variable?

Comment: Well, it points me here (anonymous function) modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4
  y modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4
  s.fontface modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4
  (anonymous function) modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4
  (anonymous function) modernizr-2.6.2.min.js:4

Comment: once you do `$scope.sessions = Sessions.gList();` it triggers the digest process and whenever you have $scope.sessions.sheet or somewhere in your html you have i.e. `{{sessions.sheet}} you will get that error, you should utilise promises here to achieve the right functionality

Comment: @maurycy, I only have `ng-repeat="session in sessions"`, there is no `sheet` in my code. Where and how should I use a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is during the time in which your http request got response,the ng-repeat  sessions in script already called. It means that the value of sessions is null and i think you try to access {{ session.sheet }} in your HTML which is undefined and so browser telling you. The solution for such problem is use $q.defer.resolve() and $q.defer.reject() for http response and error. Than pass the through $q.promise. An example is given below :

```
.service('httpService' , ['$http','$q', function($http, $q) ]{

  $http(sendConfig).then(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);

      }, function(response) {
         deferred.error(response);
      }, function(message) {
        deferred.notify(message);
      });

      return deferred.promise;

});
```

And in controller try to access this

```
httpService().then(function(res){

$scope.sessions = res;
});
```